# visualvm does not reflect the correct metaspace size?

Tags: java, performance, memory, heap-memory, visualvm

I am using `jdk1.8.0_60` . I have set jvm argument as `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1536m` to set the max metaspace size.

But in jvisualvm, i still see it 1GB. Is visualvm not updated to reflect the latest mestaspace size ?

Comment: We'll assume you're using a 64 bit JVM and run on a 64 bit operating system.  True for both?  Which OS?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31075761/java-8-reserves-minimum-1g-for-metaspace-despite-maxmetaspacesize

Comment: yes Duffymo that is correct

Answer (score 1):

This is JDK bug. See [original VisualVM report](https://java.net/jira/browse/VISUALVM-609) and corresponding 
[JDK bug 8077987](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8077987).

Answer (score 0):

Use _JAVA_OPTIONS instead of JAVA_OPTS, so the settings are system wide

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="$_JAVA_OPTIONS  -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1536m"
```