# Java - High class reserved space running out of memory

Tags: java, heroku

I'm debugging a memory problem on a Heroku dyno that has `512M` of memory. After a lot of poking and prodding, I *think* I've narrowed it down to class space not getting cleaned up for some reason. Here's the output of `jcmd <pid> VM.native_memory summary`:

```
Java Heap (reserved=163840KB, committed=163840KB)
  (mmap: reserved=163840KB, committed=163840KB)


Class (reserved=1120210KB, committed=80466KB)
  (classes #14208)
  (malloc=2002KB #18418)

  (mmap: reserved=1118208KB, committed=78464KB)

Thread (reserved=26165KB, committed=26165KB)
  (thread #45)
  (stack: reserved=25776KB, committed=25776KB)
  (malloc=144KB #222)
  (arena=244KB #89)

Code (reserved=256694KB, committed=42130KB)
  (malloc=7094KB #10281)
  (mmap: reserved=249600KB, committed=35036KB)

GC (reserved=569KB, committed=569KB)
  (malloc=29KB #279)
  (mmap: reserved=540KB, committed=540KB)

Compiler (reserved=217KB, committed=217KB)
  (malloc=86KB #290)
  (arena=131KB #3)

Internal (reserved=3116KB, committed=3116KB)
  (malloc=3084KB #16726)
  (mmap: reserved=32KB, committed=32KB)

Symbol (reserved=19560KB, committed=19560KB)
  (malloc=15812KB #163798)
  (arena=3748KB #1)

Native Memory Tracking (reserved=3649KB, committed=3649KB)
  (malloc=292KB #4629)
  (tracking overhead=3357KB)

Arena Chunk (reserved=198KB, committed=198KB)
  (malloc=198KB)
```

Here are my `JAVA_OPTS`:

```
-Xmx160m
-Xss512k
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=128M
-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=detail
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
-XX:+UseSerialGC
```

Any idea why `Class` is still reserving more than a gig of memory? Again, I'm not even totally sure class space is the issue, so any help is appreciated.

Note that I'm using some Groovy code, which can be fairly noisy in the classloader arena.

Comment: See this question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31075761/java-8-reserves-minimum-1g-for-metaspace-despite-maxmetaspacesize I think your question is a duplicate of it.

Comment: @Oleg Nice catch, but I'm using neither `-XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers` nor `-XX:+UseCompressedOops`, which would cause issues in this area, reserving the 1G as mentioned in the referenced question according to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/considerations.html#sthref66. My problem is different because the `CompressedClassSpaceSize` should not apply.

Comment: Can you check with `jcmd <pid> VM.flags` I think they are on by default.

Comment: You are a life saver. Please add your answer and point to the other question. I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java 8 is reserving 1GB of memory for compressed class pointers. If you want it to reserve less memory you can do that with `CompressedClassSpaceSize` jvm parameter. Some additional details in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31104372/1398418) and in this [guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/considerations.html) from oracle.

Note that from the oracle guide it looks like java only reserves 1GB when `UseCompressedOops` and `UseCompressedClassesPointers` jvm arguments are used but for some reason they decided not to mention that they are on by default.